# Eigen find set difference between two matrices

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to obtain the set difference between two Eigen matrices. The code:

```
void diffMatrix(
    MatrixXi &M1, // First Matrix
    MatrixXi &M2, // Second Matrix
    MatrixXi &M3, // Matrix set difference
    VectorXi &I3  // Matrix set difference indices
)
{
    // find rows in first matrix that aren't in second matrix

    // cols of M1 = M2
    assert(M1.cols() == M2.cols());

    M3.resize(M1.rows(), M1.cols());
    I3.resize(M1.rows());

    bool m2r_nonex;
    size_t k = 0;

    // get M1 rows
    for (size_t i = 0; i < M1.rows(); i++)
    {
        m2r_nonex = true;
        auto m1r = M1.row(i);

        // NOTE: this is slow

        // check M1 row is in M2
        for (size_t j = 0; j < M2.rows(); j++)
        {
            auto m2r = M2.row(j);
            if (m1r == m2r)
                m2r_nonex = false;
        }

        // if it's not in m2, add it to M3
        if (m2r_nonex)
        {
            M3.row(k) = m1r;
            I3(k) = i;
            k++;
        }
    }

    M3.conservativeResize(k, NoChange);
    I3.conservativeResize(k, NoChange);
}

MatrixXi M1, M2, M3;
VectorXi I3;

M1.resize(3, 3);
M2.resize(2, 3);

M1 << 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2;
M2 << 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2;

diffMatrix(M1, M2, M3, I3);


===========================================
M3 (Rows: 1 Cols: 3)
===========================================
[[0, 0, 0]]
```

The provided code works of course, but is slow. Ideally one would substitute the inner for loop for some more compact expression, maybe something allowing to count all occurrence of a M1 row in M2 rows in a single statement...
Is that possible?

===== EDIT =====

(following Homer512 answer)

Yes, it works. To give an idea of the performance increase... After loading 10000 records:

```
MatrixXi M1, M2, M3;
VectorXi I3;
size_t rows = 10000;

M1.resize(rows, 3);
M2.resize(rows, 3);

for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    M1(i,0) = i;
    M1(i,1) = i; 
    M1(i,2) = i;

    M2(i,0) = i + 1;
    M2(i,1) = i + 1; 
    M2(i,2) = i + 1;
}
```

with first method proposed elapsed is: 43.826125 secs; with second method proposed elapsed is: 0.017632 secs

It's about some orders of magnitude faster... Thank you for this.

Comment: I don't think there's compact expression that would work better, but you may try to use `std::set` if you can compare rows (or `std::unordered_set` if there's hash function for rows) for `M2` rows and use it to test whether `m1r` is in it.

Comment: Can you transpose the matrices? Eigen's default storage order is column-major. By comparing rows, the inner-most loop iterates over elements that are far away from each other. Changing this to columns makes writing a faster implementation much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that ought to be relatively efficient.

We start by transposing the input matrices. You want to compare rows. But [Eigen organizes its matrices column-major](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) which means that consecutive elements within a row are not stored consecutively in memory. This makes everything you do rowwise slow and everything you do column-wise fast. Ideally, you want to skip this step and simply start with the proper orientation. Or switch to row-major matrices as described in the linked Eigen documentation.

```cpp
const Eigen::MatrixXi left_transp = M1.transpose();
const Eigen::MatrixXi right_transp = M2.transpose();
```

Now for the actual star of the show: We want to use a hash set to check whether an element is in the set. We have a hash set we can use, the [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) but we need to define a suitable key to represent a vector, ideally without copying data.

Thankfully C++17 introduced [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) and related type definitions including `std::u32string_view`; perfect for binary int32 data. These types come with `std::hash` specializations and comparisons.

At this point we can build a hash table for all entries in M2.

```cpp
std::unordered_set<std::u32string_view> right_set;
right_set.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(right_transp.cols()));
const std::size_t rows = static_cast<std::size_t>(right_transp.rows());
for(auto col: right_transp.colwise()) {
    static_assert(sizeof(char32_t) == sizeof(int));
    assert(col.innerStride() == 1);
    const char32_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char32_t*>(col.data());
    right_set.emplace(ptr, rows);
}
```

In the next step we can do the same with M1 and search the hash table for duplicates.

```cpp
const Eigen::Index left_n = left_transp.cols();
I3.resize(left_n);
Eigen::Index count = 0;
for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < left_n; ++i) {
    const char32_t* ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char32_t*>(
          left_transp.col(i).data());
    const std::u32string_view view{ ptr, rows };
    if(! right_set.count(view))
        I3[count++] = i;
}
I3.conservativeResize(count);
```

All that's left is using the indices to build M3. Again, preferably without transposing.

```cpp
M3.resize(static_cast<Eigen::Index>(rows), count);
for(Eigen::Index i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    M3.col(i) = left_transp.col(I3[i]);
M3.transposeInPlace();
```

Comment: Interesting workflow. Didn't ever considered transposing to leverage column-majority...

Comment: for (auto col : right_transp.colwise()) -> for (size_t i = 0; i < right_transp.cols(); i++) as it has no iterator

Comment: But how 'diff_indices' is defined? of course I get undeclared identifier

Comment: @Kabu Re ```colwise``` iterator: It's a new feature in Eigen-3.4. If you are stuck on an older version, go with a tranditional loop. Re ```diff_indices```: That was a bug. I forgot to rename the variable when I switched from my naming scheme to yours.